# Calculating interest using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL, and have a table for a billing cycle and another for payments made in a billing cycle.

I am trying to figure out how to calculate interest based on how much amount was left after each billing cycle's last payment date. Problem is that every time a repayment is made, the interest has to be calculated on the amount remaining after that.

My thoughts on building this query are like this. Build data for all dates from last pay date of the billing cycle to today. Using partitioning, get the remaining amount for the first date. For second date, use amount from previous row and add interest to it, and then calculate interest on this one.

Unfortunately I am stuck just at the thought and can't figure out how to make this into a query!

Here's some sample data to make things easier to understand.

Billing Cycles:

```
 id  |       ends_at       
-----+---------------------
 1   | 2017-11-30
 2   | 2017-11-30
```

Payments:

```
  amount   | billing_cycle_id |  type   |         created_at         
-----------+------------------+---------+----------------------------
 6000.0000 |                1 | payment | 2017-11-15 18:40:22.151713
 2000.0000 |                1 |repayment| 2017-11-19 11:45:15.6167
 2000.0000 |                1 |repayment| 2017-12-02 11:46:40.757897
```

So if we see, user made a repayment on the 19th, so amount due for interest post ends date(30th Nov 2017), is only 4000. So, from 30th to the 2nd, interest will be calculated daily on 4000. However, from the 2nd, interest needs to be calculated on 2000 only.

Interest Calculations(Today being 2017-12-04):

```
    date    |  amount | interest 
------------+---------+----------
 2017-12-01 |    4000 |      100          // First day of pending dues.
 2017-12-02 |    2100 |     52.5          // Second day of pending dues.
 2017-12-03 |  2152.5 |  53.8125          // Third day of pending dues.
 2017-12-04 |2206.3125|                   // Fourth's day interest will be added tomorrow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is too sparse.  It doesn't make any sense to need to write this query, because over time the query will get significantly more complicated.  What happens when interest rates change over time?

The table itself (or a secondary table, depending on how you want to structure it) could have a running balance you add every time a deposit / withdrawal is made. (I suggest this table be add-only)  Otherwise you're making both the calculation and accounting far harder on yourself than it should be.  Even with the way you've presented the problem here, there's not enough information to do the calculation. (interest rate is missing)  When that's the case, your stored procedure is going to be too complicated.  Complicated means bugs, and people get irritated about bugs when you're talking about their money.